# How can I use the JS typeof operator inside an if using coffeescript?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I need to translate a piece of JavaScript code into CoffeeScript, here it is:

```
jQuery(function($) {
if (typeof ($.fn.jCarouselLite) != 'undefined') {
  $("#slider_1").jCarouselLite({
    btnNext: "#slider_1 .next",
    btnPrev: "#slider_1 .prev",
    visible: 1
  });
}
```

The if condition is causing a problem, Here's what I'm doing at that point:

```
jQuery ->
  $ = jQuery
    if typeof $.fn.jCarouselLite not 'undefined'
      $("#slider_1").jCarouselLite
        btnNext: "#slider_1 .next
        btnPrev: "#slider_1 .prev"
        visible: 1
```

But the compiler is complaining saying: **PARSE ERROR ON LINE 2: UNEXPECTED 'POST_IF'**

Can anybody help me? How can correctly translate that If condition into Coffeescript?

Thanks,

Comment: You're also missing a closing double quote in your CoffeeScript version.

Comment: thank you, I hadn't seen that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`not` is a unary operator, so I think you meant

```
if typeof $.fn.jCarouselLite isnt 'undefined'
```

... but you can just use `?`:

```
if $.fn.jCarouselLite?
```

... but that error seems like it would be caused by funny indentation, like on line 2...

Comment: I'm sorry to say, but none of those seem to work, even the compiler at http://coffeescript.org/ can't process them :( Any ideas? -Thanks for your reply!

Comment: Actually, my bad. It seems it wasn't working because the file I was translating from had Tabs (\t) in it, and that was messing things up. Why it won't work at the coffeescript site, that I really can't explain...

Comment: @JoseE, it's not working on coffeescript.org because the `if` needs to have a body. [Example](http://coffeescript.org/#try:if%20typeof%20%24.fn.jCarouselLite%20isnt%20%27undefined%27%0A%20%20statement%28%29).

Answer (score 1):

Try `unless` and using parenthesis:

```
jQuery ($) ->
  unless typeof ($.fn.jCarouselLite) is "undefined"
    $("#slider_1").jCarouselLite
      btnNext: "#slider_1 .next"
      btnPrev: "#slider_1 .prev"
      visible: 1
```

BTW, you can check things quickly with http://js2coffee.org/

Comment: Thanks for mentioning that site ! your solution is very elegant and it worked very well.

Comment: Thank you. May I ask why the other answer was accepted then?

Comment: Well, unfortunately it was my mistake why the accepted answer didn't work, but it is correct. On careful examination, I got it to work, and he was first to answer. If it was you the first, I'd have awarded it to you... but I'd be unfair this time. Sorry.